# $dim_\mathbb C V=n$ then $dim _\mathbb R V=2n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that if the dimension of a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb C$ is $n$ then the dimension of $V$ over $R$ is $2n$

I wanted to do it using isomorphisms i.e. every finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C^n$ and this one is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{2n}$ but the thing is that my teacher said that we can´t use isomorphisms in this proof, but I can´t think of any other way to prove it. Can you give me a hand please? I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: How do you define dimension?  Perhaps you should simply find a suitable basis.

Comment: If $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$, then certainly $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a linearly independent set of $n$ vectors in $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Can you find $n$ more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be a basis for $V$ over $\Bbb C$.  Then $x_1,i\,x_1,x_2,i\,x_2,\dots,x_n,i\,x_n$ (where $i = \sqrt{-1}$) is a basis for $V$ over $\Bbb R$ (prove that this is the case).